# why python requires us to use from statement when we have already loaded a module using import

Tags: python

When we `import` a module, say `os`, aren't we importing everything in it?

Then what's the use of `from moduleName import (delimiter)` should be added to the file in order for us to use its constants? and bunch of other things.

Can any one explain the exactly what `from moduleName` does when we actually have already loaded the module using `import`?

Comment: the use of `from` allows you to access the element directly. For example: `import collections; collections.defaultdict` vs `from collections import defaultdict; defaultdict`

Comment: Usually you use just `import module` _or_ `from module import stuff`, depending on what you want to have in your namespace, but not both. Can you show us some code? Maybe you are not using it right.

Comment: The only thing I usually `import from` is `from pprint import pprint` as I use it very often for debug traces in my code. Otherwise I just like have all these `.`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you just do `import sys` for example, you do input everything in it.  When you do a `from sys import exit` you import that specific module to be used without its first module name.  Basically, if you use the `from sys import exit` statment you can just call:

```
exit()
```

Instead of:

```
sys.exit()
```

It's just a way to save less time writing the full `sys.exit()` statement.  If you use it to load constants, you just allow yourself to write shorter statements to write something.  If you have questions just ask!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose I want to use `os.path.abspath`. I can import `os`, and type `os.path.abspath` every time I want to use it. Or I can write `from os.path import abspath`, and now I just need to type `abspath`.

The utility of something like:

```
import os
from os.path import abspath
```

Is that I can still reference other objects defined in `os`, like `os.path.splitext`, but if I use `abspath` frequently, I only need to type `abspath`.